# Asking "What is the size of the file?"

Tags: translation, business-japanese, computing

I am discussing via email about a file, and I want to ask "What is the size of the file?"

Here is my try: `サイズは何ですか？`

I realize it sounds weird though, and `サイズはどのぐらいですか？` might sound better but I am afraid that the `ぐらい` will imply I want an approximate size, which is not true: I want the exact size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A natural way of asking that would be:

「ファイルのサイズを[教]{おし}えてください。」

If it is for business, one could say:

「ファイルのサイズをお教えいただけますか。」

The problem with 「サイズは[何]{なん}ですか？」 is that while it is a perfectly grammatical sentence, it sounds like it was "translated" from anothet language, which it was.  When I read that part, it reminded me of the sentence 「[名前]{なまえ}は何ですか。」 which is also often said by Japanese-learners.

Comment: If I don't get an immediate response to a question like this then follow up by repeating the question using alternative words like: ファイルの大きさはいくつのメガバイト（MB）ですか。